# Copy highlighted value's entire rows to another sheet with waivable only highlighted vales

Tags: excel, vba

need to move rows whose sell is highlighted , and wholes sell is not highlighted they are not move, and value is not highlighted show as blank.

highlighted

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific problem did you have getting your idea to work? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Do want to `copy` or `move` the rows with highlight cells to to other sheet?

Comment: copy and past .

Comment: Why are those cells highlighted? Is this configured manually or is this the result of conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Interior.ColorIndex property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.colorindex?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm551074)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim bHeader As Boolean
    Dim rRow As Range, c As Range
    Const SRC_SHT = "Sheet1" ' modify as needed
    Const DES_SHT = "Sheet2"
    Set rngData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    bHeader = True
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Cells.Clear
        For Each rRow In rngData.Rows
            If bHeader Then
                rRow.Copy .Range("A1")
                bHeader = False
            Else
                For Each c In rRow.Cells
                    If c.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
                        rRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]